# 404 errors for javascripts and css at server end

Tags: javascript, css, jsp, http-status-code-404

I want to know why for 404 errors of a js or css or images the container/application server doesn't display a error page in the browser configured in the web.xml. Also how to know which file caused the 404 error in the error page configured in web.xml. I need to invalidate the user session in the error page but i want to know which type of file or which file caused the 404 error.

My Web.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"       
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>page1.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<error-page>
<error-code>404</error-code>
<location>/page2.jsp</location>
</error-page>
</web-app>
```

page1.jsp :-

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="abc.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<%
System.out.println("page 1");
%>
</body>
</html>
```

In this sample application abc.js does not exist.
page2.jsp:-

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body> 
<%
 System.out.println("page 2");
 System.out.println(request.getRequestURI());
%>
</body>
</html>
```

The output i get is :-

```
page 2    
/Test404/page2.jsp
```

I want to know why page 1 was not printed in the console.

Also i want to know which file (in this case abc.js) caused the page2.jsp to run.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Not only do you simply ask, "Why is this not working" but you provide no code to even give us a shot at helping you.

Comment: @SimplyCraig..as i am new to stackoverflow, i didnt know about how to add code and all..i will definitely keep that in mind for next time

Answer (score 0):

I use Xenu to find these.  Try it, you'll like it!

Comment: ..can you provide some links to understand this?